# Passing Struct Pointers to Functions That Take Interface Pointers

Tags: go, pointers, struct, interface, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to understand the issue(s) with functions that take interface pointers as arguments, but still don't totally understand the issue, so apologies if this is a repeat question. While I understand the general sentiment is that pointers to interfaces aren't typically needed, I feel like I'm actually in a situation where it would be useful to implement them. Please feel free to tell me if that's not the case, though

I plan to get OHLC data from multiple security exchanges. I'm currently coding bots for crypto exchanges, but also plan to have bots for Forex and Stock exchanges/brokers. The goal is for the OHLC responses from each exchange to write to the `OHLCVals` struct. The OHLC responses aren't typically the same between exchanges, so that can create a problem which I'm hoping to solve with interfaces

Each bot will have its own `OHLCResponseHolder` struct (the `KrakenOHLCResponseHolder` is an example) that will implement the methods of the `OhlcResponseHolder` interface. This struct holds some "metadata" about the OHLC subscription, which is typically exchange specific. The list will actually hold the OHLC data for each candle in separate nodes, with the `Data` field for each node also being an interface. With every exchange having its own `OHLCResponseHolder` struct, I believe I can solve most issues with the `Vals` field in the `OHLCVals` struct being an interface. Because I need to update the lists in the `OhlcResponseHolder` map as new data comes in, I believe that I need to be using a pointer map to be able to make those updates.

I believe that using interface pointers may be the best solution in this case, as the only other thing I could think of would be to use generics. If I remember correctly though, generics cannot be used with maps. Even if they are able to used with maps, it could get very tedious, as I plan to support many exchanges (hopefully 10-20), which would lead to generic functions with many accepted data types and lots of one off edge cases to test for

With my use case for functions taking pointers to interfaces out of the way, I'm having some trouble passing structs pointers to functions that take interface pointers. Here are the interfaces and structs that I currently have coded:

```
type Candle interface {
    GetCandle() Candle
    GetStartTime() UnixTime
    GetEndTime() UnixTime
    GetHigh() decimal.Decimal
    SetHigh(num decimal.Decimal)
    GetLow() decimal.Decimal
    SetLow(num decimal.Decimal)
    GetClose() decimal.Decimal
    SetClose(num decimal.Decimal)
    GetVWAP() decimal.Decimal
    SetVWAP(num decimal.Decimal)
    GetVolume() decimal.Decimal
    SetVolume(num decimal.Decimal)
    GetCount() int
    SetCount(num int)
}

type Node struct {
    Data Candle
    Next *Node
}

type List interface {
    GetList() List
    AddToEnd(n *Node)
    Print(locker *sync.RWMutex)
    IsEmpty() bool
    GetLast() *Node
}

type list struct {
    Head   *Node
    Last   *Node
    Length uint
}

func NewList(head *Node, last *Node, length uint) *list {
    return &list{Head: head, Last: last, Length: length}
}

func (l *list) GetList() List {
    return l
}

func (l *list) AddToEnd(n *Node) {
    if l.Head == nil {
        l.Head = n
        l.Last = n
        l.Length++
        return
    }
    tmp := l.Last
    tmp.Next = n
    l.Last = n
    l.Length++
}

func (l list) Print(locker *sync.RWMutex) {
    locker.RLock()
    tmp := l.Head
    for tmp != nil {
        fmt.Println(string("\033[34m"), tmp.Data, string("\033[0m"))
        tmp = tmp.Next
    }
    locker.RUnlock()
    fmt.Println()
}

func (l list) IsEmpty() bool {
    return l.Length == 0
}

func (l *list) GetLast() *Node {
    return l.Last
}

type OhlcResponseHolder interface {
    GetChannelID() int
    GetList() *List
    GetInterval() int64
}

type KrakenOHLCResponseHolder struct {
    ChannelID   int
    Interval    int64
    ChannelName string
    Pair        string
    List        shared_types.List
}

func (o KrakenOHLCResponseHolder) GetChannelID() int {
    return o.ChannelID
}

func (o *KrakenOHLCResponseHolder) GetList() *shared_types.List {
    return &o.List
}

func (o KrakenOHLCResponseHolder) GetInterval() int64 {
    return o.Interval
}

type OHLCValHolder interface {
    Set(key int, data *OhlcResponseHolder)
    RLock()
    RUnlock()
    Lock()
    Unlock()
    GetVals() map[int]*OhlcResponseHolder
    GetMutex() *sync.RWMutex
}

type OHLCVals struct {
    Vals  map[int]*shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder
    Mutex sync.RWMutex
}

func (ohlcVals *OHLCVals) Set(key int, data *shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder) {
    if ohlcVals.Vals == nil {
        ohlcVals.Vals = make(map[int]*shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder)
    }
    ohlcVals.Vals[key] = data
}

func (ohlcVals *OHLCVals) RLock() {
    ohlcVals.Mutex.RLock()
}

func (ohlcVals *OHLCVals) RUnlock() {
    ohlcVals.Mutex.RUnlock()
}

func (ohlcVals *OHLCVals) Lock() {
    ohlcVals.Mutex.Lock()
}

func (ohlcVals *OHLCVals) Unlock() {
    ohlcVals.Mutex.Unlock()
}

func (ohlcVals *OHLCVals) GetVals() map[int]*shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder {
    return ohlcVals.Vals
}

func (ohlcVals *OHLCVals) GetMutex() *sync.RWMutex {
    return &ohlcVals.Mutex
}
```

This is the context in which the code is being used:

```
func HandleOHLCResponse(v *types.OHLCResponse, ohlcMap *shared_types.OHLCValHolder) {
    (*ohlcMap).RLock()
    if subID, found := (*ohlcMap).GetVals()[v.ChannelID]; found { // if channelID already exists in the map, then...
        // stuff
        fmt.Println(2+2)    
    } else { // if the channel id cannot be found in the map
        interval, _ := strconv.ParseInt(v.ChannelName[len(v.ChannelName)-1:], 10, 64)
        v.OHLCArray.StartTime.Time = v.OHLCArray.EndTime.Add(-time.Minute * time.Duration(interval))
        node := shared_types.Node{Data: &v.OHLCArray, Next: nil}
        tmp := types.KrakenOHLCResponseHolder{ChannelID: v.ChannelID, ChannelName: v.ChannelName, Pair: v.Pair, Interval: interval, List: shared_types.NewList(&node, &node, 1)}
        (*ohlcMap).RUnlock()

        (*ohlcMap).Lock()
        (*ohlcMap).Set(tmp.ChannelID, &tmp)
        (*ohlcMap).Unlock()
    }
}
```

This is the error i get when i pass `&tmp` as an argument to `(*ohlcMap).Set(tmp.ChannelID, &tmp)`: cannot use &tmp (value of type *"bruit/bruit/clients/kraken/types".KrakenOHLCResponseHolder) as *shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder value in argument to (*ohlcMap).Set: *"bruit/bruit/clients/kraken/types".KrakenOHLCResponseHolder does not implement *shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder (type *shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder is pointer to interface, not interface)

Would greatly appreciate any help on this

Comment: Why are you explicitly dereferencing the receiver variables when calling methods on them? Is this some kind of OCD or do you actually think you *have* to do that to make the code work?

Comment: The error ought to be clear though: you cannot use `*T` as type `*I` even if `T` or `*T` implement `I`. Type `*I` is not an interface type. It is a pointer type. A concrete type, not an abstract one. You cannot pass arguments of arbitrary types in place of parameters with concrete types. Even if the arbitrary type "satisfies part of the concrete type". It's analogous to type `T` not being identical to `[]T`. If you have a function that takes a slice of strings then it is not enough to pass a single string.

Comment: The resolve the immediate error however, you could simply first convert `temp` to the interface type and store the result of that in a new variable and then pass the address of that new variable as the argument to the `Set` method. And if you want to avoid the extra variable you can do the conversion straight from the struct literal of the concrete type, i.e. `tmp := shared_types.OhlcResponseHolder(types.KrakenOHLCResponseHolder{ ... })`

Comment: @mkopriva VSCode was giving me error messages if I didn't dereference them, so that's why they're always dereferenced. Honestly just assumed I had to do it that way... Thanks VSCode. Appreciate the help though. This makes perfect sense why it wasn't working and everything is working as expected now

Comment: Well... my bad, I've now noticed that `shared_types.OHLCValHolder` is an interface type. And if you have a variable that is a pointer to an interface type then you will need to do the ugly dereferencing when trying to invoke the interface's methods. However this, in my defence, just shows that you are misusing interface-pointers and proves all the stuff you've read about them not being needed right.

Comment: Pointers to interfaces have one and only one use case. The updating of the callers **variable**. I'm aware of no other use for them.

Comment: @mkopriva no worries. there's a lot of code, so it's not easy to catch. honest question, but what would the better solution be then? The only other solution I can think of would be generic functions, but from what i understand, they can't be implemented on a map. is there another way for me to get a pointer to the map while still having it take "generic" data types? i'm making mutations to the list in the first part of the HandleOHLCResponse func, as well as when making the map. from my point of view, i'm updating the caller's variable

Comment: From a quick scan of the code neither `ohlcMap` nor its elements need to be pointers. Only the dynamic types that implement those interfaces, **if they need to be able to modify *themselves* through the interface methods** need to be pointers. And remember that an interface value, under the hood, already **has** a pointer to the underlying data. If you still believe that you really need a pointer to an interface, can you try and prove it by providing two side-by-side simplified examples of your code, one with pointer-to-interface and one with non-pointer interface, where the 2nd one breaks?

Comment: Do not use pointer to interface, dead simple.

Comment: Ok I see. I'll try not using pointer interfaces and see what happens

Comment: @mkopriva apologies about the late response. life happens sometimes lol. i did get the chance to go through the code and change everything from pointer interfaces to just interfaces, and I do have the same functionality as before. you were 100% right about not needing pointer interfaces in this case. appreciate the time you took to explain everything! it turned out to be a dumb question, but we're here to learn

Answer (score 0):

The type `*types.OhlcResponseHolder` is a pointer to an interface type.

A value `&tmp` can't be passed as the second argument to `Set` of type `*types.OhlcResponseHolder`:

- the [underlying type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Underlying_types) of `&tmp` is `KrakenOHLCResponseHolder`
- the underlying type of `*types.OhlcResponseHolder` is `types.OhlcResponseHolder`
- these types are [not identical](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_identity) (named types are identical to themselves only)
- hence `&tmp` is [not assignable](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) to `*types.OhlcResponseHolder`
- hence `&tmp` [can't be converted](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) to `*types.OhlcResponseHolder` (see the first rule: *x is assignable to T*)

Still you can use `tmp` if you use an intermediate variabe:

```
    var h_tmp types.OhlcResponseHolder = tmp
    (*ohlcMap).Set(tmp.ChannelID, &h_tmp)
```

This will works since the underlying type of `&h_tmp` is `types.OhlcResponseHolder` and it is identical to the type of the second parameter of the function `Set`.

Here is a simplified example: https://go.dev/play/p/zCAe56jg_re

The problem with this recipie is that `KrakenOHLCResponseHolder` doesn't implement `OhlcResponseHolder` - the method `GetList` is defined for pointer receiver.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, the issue is that pointer methods can't be used on pointer interfaces? I guess I'm having a hard time understanding why that's an issue when it seems like it's still possible to use pointer receivers if you just dereference the interface. For whatever reason, I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around this concept

Comment: @Grant looks like you treat pointers like in C - for keeping side effects in operations. In Go there is another paradigm. The values are passed by value, and they keep pointers internally to share the state between copies. After I got used to it, the life became much easier. No need to worry about leaked state and inconsisting duplicates. See the example in my answer - it uses an int pointer to keep the state, and the values are passed by value.